# Defining object method that accesses objects values?

Tags: ruby

I have the following string and want to define a method to append the letter 'd' to the end of it.  One way I can do this is with the `class << str` idiom.

```
str = 'abc'


class << str
   def frob
      return self + "d"
   end
end
```

Is there a way I can do this with the following syntax?

```
def str.frob
        return str + 'd'
end
```

When I try to do this I get the `undefined local variable or method 'str' for "abc":String (NameError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = 'abc'
def str.frob
  p self
  return self + 'd'
end
p str.frob 
# >> "abc"
# >> "abcd"
str.singleton_methods # => [:frob]
str.object_id # => 79771730
```

You got the error because *singleton_method*  `#frob` has its own local scope,where `str` is not legal. Thus you got the legitimate error. That method is created on the object "abc" having *object_id,79771730*.

Comment: What does the syntax `p self` mean?

Comment: @user784637 `p` is like `puts`,`print` i used to show you what `self` is inside the method `#frob`..